# CSS flexbox vertical stack with bottom-anchored element

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I use flexbox layouts to create a vertical stack (column) of divs with one div anchored to the bottom of the container?

```
|--------|
|  div1  |
|  div2  |
|  div3  |
|        |
|        |
|        |
| fixed1 |
|--------|
```

For example, in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mv241w0x/1/) I want Items 1, 2, and 3 to be horizontally centered and vertically aligned to the top and Fixed Item to be horizontally centered and vertically aligned to the bottom.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="fixed">Fixed Item</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    height: 50%;
    background: #EEE;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content: center;
}

.fixed {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky, because it seems that `align-self` only works with `flex-direction:row`.

I did manage to get it "kind-of" working by wrapping your `.fixed` element with another flexbox.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb1xj5y3/).

Comment: Would you be able to get all the items horizontally centered in the main div as well?